# Can't make the app save variables when it exits

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making an app where the user keeps pressing a button to get in-app money, my problem is whenever the app is closed or paused when i return the app's Money counter resets to zero. So i tried to make a Shared Preferences code to save my variables when the app pauses or stops, However when i resume the app the Counter doesn't reset to zero but as soon as i click on the button to generate money it resets to zero? Any help would be appreciated.

The Code being executed when the button is pressed:

```
    myBalance += 1;
    TextView balanceShow = findViewById(R.id.balanceShow);
    balanceShow.setText("Balance: " + myBalance + "Coin");
```

And this is the code executed on the application exit event (The code that saves the user balance):

```
    TextView balanceShow = findViewById(R.id.balanceShow);
    String balance = balanceShow.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("MySavedData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putString("BALANCE", balance);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And finally this is the code executed on the app's resume that loads the user's balance when he comes back:

```
    TextView balanceShow = findViewById(R.id.balanceShow);
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("MySavedData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String balance = data.getString("BALANCE", "No Data Found!");
    balanceShow.setText(balance);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To make things more clear:

1- The app starts with a "0" Coins balance.

2- I click on the button, to generate "1" Coin every time i press it which triggers the first code i posted.

3- Let's say i made "80" Coin.

4- Now i close the app.

5- I open the app, I find that my balance is "80" Coins. Great!

6- I press on the button, then the balance resets to "0" Coins and starts from scratch again!

Please help it's been hours since i am trying to figure what's happening, and i couldn't, What's wrong with the code? Also i tried numerous other saving codes and they all crash the app, this is the only Saving code that seems to work with me, Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You should post the entire portion of each method used and variable declarations that aren't show to make it more clear what's going on. But, I think `myBalance` is probably 0 instead of what you have in your prefs so that is what is resetting it to 0.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. In particular, you must show which class and method contains each of the code snippets that you posted here.

Comment: You should use the Android Studio debugger to see what your code is doing. Set breakpoints at the beginning of each of the above snippets then run your app in debug mode. Follow each of the steps that you describe and view the values of variables.

Comment: here is my code: https://i.imgur.com/0a7L0CZ.png?1

Comment: They are located in the Main Activity.java

Comment: It's actually the only class i have in the project

Comment: @EpicDragon68 take out your code form onStop to onPause. it may help you achieve what you want

Comment: There is no "application exit event" on Android. You can run code when your foreground activity loses focus (`onPause`) or becomes invisible (`onStop`). If you want to save in-progress state without persisting to disk, save it in `onSaveInstanceState`, restore it in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TextView balanceShow = findViewById(R.id.balanceShow);
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("MySavedData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String balance = data.getString("BALANCE", "No Data Found!");
    balanceShow.setText(balance);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Herein lies your problem. You are only updating the value of the TextField, whereas the value of the counter behind the TextField (here `myBalance`) is zero. Instead of saving the data stored in the TextField to SharedPreferences, you should instead store the integer data in the `myBalance` counter to the preferences and load that when you resume the app.

In short, in order to save coins:

```
private void saveCoinsToPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("MySavedData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putInt("BALANCE", myBalance);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And in order to retrieve coins:

```
private int retrieveCoins() {
    TextView balanceShow = findViewById(R.id.balanceShow);
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("MySavedData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    myBalance = data.getInt("BALANCE", -1);
    balanceShow.setText("Balance: " + myBalance + "Coin");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Tried it, it gives an error at the "Save Coin Code" in the line:        ////////editor.putInt("BALANCE", myBalance); /////////         the error says: Expecting Int, found Double

Comment: Is your myBalance variable a double? If so, try `editor.putString( "BALANCE", String.valueOf(myBalance));` and in retrieveCoins, try `myBalance = Double.parseDouble( data.getString( "BALANCE", "-1" ));`

Comment: I'd suggest not converting doubles to strings and back. Save the data as the type it is. SharedPreferences has an option for floats if if you need that. Though if you're dealing with "money", you probably want to use ints and save the value "in cents".

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Man! Thank you soooo much! It worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer helped you out, please mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void saveCoins(Context context, String coin) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
        spe.putString(context.getString(R.string.pref_coin), coin);
        spe.apply();
    }
```

to retrieve the coins

```
private String getPaymentSelected(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        return sp.getString(c.getString(R.string.pref_coin), "0");
    }
```

create a string variable pref_coin in strings.xml (inside values folder)

Comment: how do i call the retrieve function? Whenever i do it gives an error: //getPaymentSelected(); in MainActivity cannot be applied to ()

Comment: in MainActivity try this 
balance = getPaymentSelected(this) ;

Comment: i am sorry if i am being annoying but what if my coin variable is a double?

Comment: No problem mate, sorry i was not online. Glad that the issue got resolved.